# Copying Environment Variables in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, environment-variables

How can I copy the value of an environment variable into another environment variable?  I'm updating a DOS batch script for use on Windows XP.  Let's say that I have environment variable `FOO`, which contains `some\file\path`, and I need to make an exact copy of this file in environment variable `BAR`.  How is that accomplished?

Variable `FOO` is setup as such:

> setx FOO %MY_ROOT%\some\file\path

How do I make `BAR` equal `FOO` by only referencing `FOO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Setx BAR %FOO%`

You have to be careful with SETX though, as it doesn't apply the variables set to the current CMD window.

So you'd have to open a CMD, run `Setx FOO path`, exit the current CMD window and/or open a new one, at which point %FOO% will take effect, and you can then assign FOO to BAR with `Setx BAR %FOO%`.

You can use `Set` to assign variables that work immediately in the current CMD session, but Set's scope is only within the current CMD session, so you may need to use a combination of both.

Comment: The equal sign (`=`) causes an error.

Comment: Yeah, I realized I had erroneously stuck those in there (that's `Set`'s syntax), so I edited them out. :)